# Get a range of cells from a closed workbook in a VBA code run on another workbook

Tags: vba

How do I get a range of cells from a closed workbook in a VBA code run on another workbook?

I am trying the ExecuteExcel4Macro() function. I can not get it to work for a range of more than one cell.

Comment: you added no code for any help so let me show you.  In the search bar type closed workbook - there is a so question for getting information from one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to access a range using ExecuteExcel4Macro. You probably would have better results using [ADO](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973)

You can also try something like this:

```
Sub getARange()
    With Range("A2:B4")
        .Formula = "='C:\[source.xlsx]Input'!A2" 
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The above will copy it into your current workbook. you may want to do something like this or store it in a range variable depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I see you copy the range this way into a sheet. I can read this range from this worksheet and store it in a range variable or variant. Is there a way to store it in a (variant) variable directly? If so, could you please write it in your answer?

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly this way but if you want to do a "Application.Workbooks.Open" and open the sheet you are copying from then it's quite easy. I guess a work around would be to just dim Arr() as variant then add Arr = .value after the .formula and delete the data from your master sheet.